# How to filter by `User_Mention` in `SearchBar`

Tags: swift, string, swiftui, searchbar

i am using a searchBar to allow the user to filter the list by what he typed in.

but how to allow this list to be searched by "@" User_Mention too?

this is my try but it does not work:

```
      var searchText = ""
var body : some View{
    List(observedData.datas.filter{
        $0.msg.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) || searchText.lowercased() == "" ||
        $0.name.lowercased().contains("@"+searchText.lowercased()) || "@"+searchText.lowercased() == ""

    }

         ))

    {
        i in
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            CellCard(userId:i.userId,user: i.name)
        }
    }

    .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved like this:

```
$0.msg.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) || "@\($0.name)".lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) || searchText.lowercased() == ""
```